# Implicit declaration glCreateShader()?

Tags: c, opengl, glew, freeglut

I am getting warning from gcc. Warning is:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘glCreateShader’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  137 |  unsigned int vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

I included the headers as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
```

And I compile the program as follows:

```
gcc main.c -lglut -lGL -lGLEW -lGLU -lm -o snakeGame
```

And My main function code is here:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i=0; i<snake_size; ++i){
        snake[i] = 0;
    }

//glut set
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowSize(window_x, window_y);
    glutInitWindowPosition(window_position_x, window_position_y);
    glutInitDisplayMode(display_mode);

    int window = glutCreateWindow("snake game");

    glutDisplayFunc(display_function);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard_function);
    glutIdleFunc(idle_function);

//opengl set

    unsigned int vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

    glutMainLoop();

    glutDestroyWindow(window);
    printf("game over\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Most likely there is a problem with the headers.

BTW I am using linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per Khronos](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/index_gl.php#headers) only GL 1.1 functions are declared in `gl.h`.  GL 1.2 and above live in [`glext.h`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/api/GL/glext.h) and [need to be acquired at run-time](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions).

Though [since you're using GLEW you should `#include <GL/glew.h>` instead](https://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html), since that will have declarations for *all* GL functions.  Don't forget to initialize GLEW.

Answer (score 0):

[Load OpenGL Functions](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions)

> Loading OpenGL Functions is an important task for initializing OpenGL after creating an OpenGL context. You are strongly advised to use an OpenGL Loading Library instead of a manual process.

[OpenGL Loading Library](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library)

> An OpenGL Loading Library is a library that loads pointers to OpenGL functions at runtime, core as well as extensions. This is required to access functions from OpenGL versions above 1.1 on most platforms.

[GLEW](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#GLEW_(OpenGL_Extension_Wrangler))

```
GLenum err = glewInit(); //loads all procs
```

More on how to use GLEW: https://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html